# Weird id result on CPython IntObject

Tags: python

I write three lines of same code and get different result, firstly I run it in one interactive shell:

```
>>> a = 10000
>>> b = 10000
>>> a is b
False

>>> a = 10000; b = 10000; a is b
True
```

Then I have one Python file that contains:

```
a = 10000
b = 10000
print a is b
```

I run it and get `True`

My Python environment:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

What is going on here? Everyone is talking about compilation, is there anyone know how does interactive shell compile and run these lines of code?

Comment: The code to run a single line in the shell is implemented here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/pythonrun.c#L1373. However, it doesn't differ from what is described here, compiling the full line to byte-code and then executing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put either into a function, it will also evaluate `True`. What's happening is that Python makes a list of constants used when compiling a function into bytecode, and equal constants will be "collapsed" into one value that is loaded two times. It looks like the interactive interpreter does the same when compiling one line of code*

So here's the bytecode for one of these functions obtained using `dis` -- it's actually the same for either method *except* for the line numbers, so I am not copying both here.

```
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (10000)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (10000)
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             12 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             15 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             18 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
             21 RETURN_VALUE
```

This is for:

```
def func():
    a = 10000; b = 10000; return a is b
from dis import dis
dis(func)
```

Note that both of the `LOAD_CONST` lines have the same argument. This is a reference to an index in `func.__code__.co_consts` which is a tuple. Element 1 of that tuple is the int object `10000`.

Just for completeness' sake, here's the disassembly of the original one-liner `a = 10000; b = 10000; a is b` if you `compile()` it:

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (10000)
              3 STORE_NAME               0 (a)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (10000)
              9 STORE_NAME               1 (b)
             12 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             15 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
             18 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
             21 POP_TOP
             22 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE
```

It's fundamentally similar, except for the line number/const number, `NAME` vs `FAST` and the ending from `POP_TOP` on. Whereas if you assign the values on separate lines, it's not doing this with the constants so it's creating a new int object each time.

*To add a bit more intrigue, if I put the one-line version into my IPython notebook, `a is b` is `False`.

Comment: I think it might be splitting on semicolons. If I add another statement after a `print(a is b)` it still prints false. But if I switch to `a, b = 10000, 10000; a is b` it becomes true.

Comment: Interesting, I'll check that a bit further :)

Comment: I had the wrong impression of what IPython is doing, since I'm doing it as a stated (executing all but the last expression). IPython compiles each "nearly-top-level" node, i.e. each line or block separately, see https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py#L2877

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a compile-time optimisation. In the first case you are compiling `a = 10000` and then `b = 10000`, so the byte-code compiler has no (simple) way of determining their identity.

In the other cases the compiler sees that `a` and `b` are initialised using the same literal and are not changed afterwards.

This has nothing to do with the small integer optimisation. That one also works for expressions, i.e.

```
>> a = 256; b = 256; a is b
True
```

but

```
>> a = 256; b = 256; a + 1 is b + 1
False
```

The respective code is part of Python's *peephole optimization* (see https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/peephole.c).

Answer (score 0):

although a fresh of python, try to explain this. Statement "is" will figure out the content of the thing is the same or not. In your example, if "is" used, python will check "a" and "b" pointing to the same thing or not. If you change your program like this:
a=1
b=1
a is b
It will print True
May be it relate to the python's method on how to store the value

Comment: This is wrong. Identity (`a is b`) and equality (`a == b`) are not the same in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, actually these 10000 that have the same id are located in the compiled code object::

```
>>> code = compile("a = 10000; b = 10000; a is b", "<string>", "exec")
>>> code.co_consts
(10000, None)
```

The compiler does some optimization, and 10000 is just created once, because 10000 is immutable:)